# Importing contacts using their phone in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to use [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) to import contacts to my account, I have their phone numbers and I can import them with this code:

```
result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
    contacts = [types.InputPhoneContact(
        client_id = 0,
        phone = utils.parse_phone('+xxxxxxxx'),
        first_name = 'first',
        last_name = 'second'
    )]
))
print(result.stringify())
```

Where `+xxxxxxxx` is a valid phone number, the above code does not cause any exceptions, however, the `imported` attribute of `result` sometimes is an empty list which means no contacts were imported and sometimes it contains my imported contact.

Why is it empty for some phones and not for some others?

Could you please help me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not all phone numbers have a telegram account ...

Comment: @Feodoran Thanks a lot, a friend sent me some numbers and claimed they all have accounts, but now I am sure some of them do not have accounts, thanks a lot. For these numbers I would get some data in the `popular_invites` attribute of the response, do you know what does this mean?